# Поправить текст в профиле нового участника про репутацию

Tags: дефект, предложение, статус-завершено, локализация, профиль-участника

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Несогласованно основное и придаточное предложения. Нет смысла в слове "опубликовано". Плюс, голосовать могут не только за "полезные" сообщения. Ну и в "Репутация показывает, насколько сообщество вам благодарно." точка не нужна.

Ну и да, привилегии не получаются, а открываются. Или же, они "становятся доступны".

В оригинале там:

> When users upvote your helpful posts, you'll earn reputation and
>   unlock new privileges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://ru.traducir.win/string/1887

Предложил:

> Когда участники голосуют за ваши сообщения, вы зарабатываете репутацию
>   и открываете новые привилегии.

https://ru.traducir.win/string/1952 убрал точку.